# How can I add a custom-style text in the editor through the button click event?

Tags: reactjs, lexical-editor

I expect that through the click event of the button,
A piece of text can be injected behind $selection in the current editor, and has a customized style

example:

```
<span class"custom-style">MyFriendName</span>
```

---

### trying now

I go to read the similar plugin in lexical-editor plugin,
This effect is what I want to achieve, but this effect is currently converted into a hashtag tag by inputting text. I hope that this tag can be injected into the back of $selection through a button

[lexical-editor demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e75UQ.png)

Result Expected screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1C4f.png)

Comment: Add css for the `className` to achieve the result you want. class must be changed to className